# Why is the first item in select menu always empty?

Tags: cakephp, select

Using CakePHP, I created select-option form element with:

```
echo $form->select('items', $numeration , array('selected' => 0));
```

It creates selection box, but the first option is always empty.

How can I get rid of that empty option? I did not manage to do anything with `showEmpty` option...

please help....
:-((

UPDATED:

cakephp code

```
echo $form->select('myOptions', array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c'), array('empty'=>false));
```

creates next html:

```
<select id="myOptions" name="data[myOptions]">
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

what is wrong, and why do i have empty element?!

Comment: Does `$numeration` have an empty element? Do a `debug` to be sure.

Comment: nope, array numeration is created just before i add first element in it

Comment: Does the $numeration array actually have an element 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's better to use:

```
$this->Form->input('items', array('options'=>$numeration));
```

By default it's without empty element. but to force it fully use

```
$this->Form->input('items', array('empty'=>false, 'options'=>$numeration));
```

Answer (score 11):

According to the [docs](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperselect) the third argument is the default item to be selected. If you don't want an empty option to appear change your code to:

```
echo $form->select('items', $numeration , NULL, array('empty' => false));
```

Comment: Cakephp cookbook [select documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select)

Answer (score 3):

This works under 2.3:

```
$options = array('0'=>'Zero','1'=>'One');
echo $this->Form->select('field-name',$options,array('empty'=>false));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but, if you are having trouble with **CakePHP 1.2** (yes, I know it sucks to use such an old version), the correct way is:

```
$form->select(string $fieldName, array $options, mixed $selected, array $attributes, boolean $showEmpty)
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#select